# What are the stars/constellations a beginner/enthusiast can easily identify?

Tags: star, amateur-observing, constellations

I was just wondering what are some of the stars, constellations or any other things that one can just identify by looking up at the night sky.

For example, when ever i look up, I immediately see Orion and can identify Betelgeuse, Rigel, Bellatrix. Apart from that i can identify some of the bright stars liike sirius , vega.
So, what other stars are there that one can easily identify and point?

Comment: Any library or bookshop will have books that provide an introduction to the night sky. Also try this google search http://www.google.com/search?q=constellations+map&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:l

Comment: You can learn about any of them. People may have favourite parts of the sky (mine is coma berenices). But that is a subjective, matter of taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies throughout the year. A book or [a website with maps](http://starryskies.com/The_sky/constellations/index.html) will help.

In Spring, Leo and Boötes dominate the southern skies, with Coma Berencies between them

In Summer, the summer triangle of Deneb, Altair and Vega is seen, with Cygnus flying along the Milky Way, and the rich star fields of Saggitarius closer to the horizon.

In Autumn there is the square of Pegasus, with Andomeda riding, past Perseus

And in Winter, Orion dominates the southern skies, with his dogs following.

In the North, Cassiopea and the Ursa Major, are on opposite sides of the Pole star.

Comment: Do you have any book recommendations?

Answer (score 4):

In the Fall (early morning) and the Winter (early-late evening), Orion is a large an easily identifiable constellation.

In the Spring (early morning) and the Summer (early-late evening), Cygnus and Pegasus are two large and easily identifiable constellations.

Check out an application called [Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org).  It's free and available for every current platform and has a large database.

Comment: Yeah, i know about stellarium. I have used it before and it is really amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you look up, if your northern sky is away from a city, locating Polaris will anchor you because it is the closest relatively bright star to the north celestial pole. It stays in the same place. Every night and every day it is where it is. No matter what time of year, Polaris will be the base point for locating other northern constellations.